# generate an excel file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I'm developing an application on C#. This is a web application. As a part of this application, I need to generate an excel file that will be store into the DB. This mean that the user won't see/open the file on the browser. So I was thinking of using a thread that will generate the excel file and store to DB. So my question is: What is the best library for generating excel files tanking in consideration that my excel file will have data and graphics generated from the data?

PS: remeber that this process will be executed on the server side.

Thanks,

Comment: This "question" has been asked 100000000 times!

Comment: I don't know if it's "the best" but I've used http://epplus.codeplex.com/ with success.

Comment: Look at the "Related" posts here to the right >>

Comment: I used the [OpenXML sdk](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

I have used OpenXML (for image insertion) and ClosedXML (when we have only data and no image). ClosedXML does not support image addition into worksheet yet.

Comment: with image you mean charts?

Comment: @AngeloGabrielEscuderoVía Yes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the Excel.exe itself as reference, working directly with the Excel Interop.